# Webpage deployment stability

Tags: c#, .net, iis, hosting

I’ve developed a .net core 3.1 website. This website uses a globalization and localization to translate the webpage strings like this reference: [globalization and localization in .Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1). When I’m running it from visual studio, it works very well, but when I deploy it to IIS, constantly it returns a 503 error, in the browser network requests logs, I saw the error occurs after a lot of localizations requests. There’s no server exceptions, I think the problema occurs because the requests amount.. someone knows how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: could you please share the error message in English?

Comment: “The service is unavailable”

Comment: try to add the asp.net logging web.config with stdoutLogEnabled and get more detail about the issue [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log).make sure application pool is started.check the event viewer logs.